# Saving data to the cloud

Tags: cloud, toit

The Toit documentation indicates that one of the advantages of the system is the simplicity and reliability of saving data received by the application from the sensors & etc on the cloud. There is even a special SDK for this. True, I did not find anything about this in the examples, so the question is: how to do this? Below is a small application that generates a list of numbers. I want to save it on the cloud. How update saveDataOnCloud procedure to solve the problem?

```
import math

getData points -> List :
  list := []
  period := 4*math.PI
  step := period/points
  for i := 0; i < points; i++ :
    list.add (2*(math.sin i*step))
  return list 
   
saveDataOnCloud data/List :
 log("save on cloud -> $data")

main :
  data := getData 128
  saveDataOnCloud data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To transfer the data to the cloud in would use the PubSub library to transfer the data and json to encode it:

```
saveDataOnCloud data/List:
  pubsub.publish "cloud:myPoints" 
    json.encode data
```

Then you can fetch it using the GRPC PubSub API: https://github.com/toitware/api/blob/master/proto/toit/api/pubsub/subscribe.proto

Note: toit does not offer long-term storage but only transient transfers of data to/from your devices and server applications.

Comment: Data persistence really works. I checked. Can a subscriber receive this data stored by publisher? How should it look like?